# HttpRequest.getHeader('Content-Length')) returns null

Tags: httprequest

Trying to debug some problematic integration issue. After executing

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody('asdf');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://sample.site.com/endpoint');
HTTPResponse response = http.send( req );
system.debug('headers ' + req.getHeader('Content-Length'));
```

User_debug comes up as null. Any reason why?

I can see from server side that Header is set, but wonder why I can't get it via getHeader method?

Also, I cannot override Content-Length with `setHeader('Content-Length', 5');`

Comment: Why does it matter? I know why Content-Length doesn't appear in getHeader, but why do you care if you can or cannot see it?

Comment: Having some disputes with third party API. The only way I found the requests to time out (via curl) is when I set content length higher then reality (server keeps waiting for additional data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content-Length is a header that's automatically calculated on your behalf. You can set it, but it'll be ignored (because the Body attribute will determine the content length header automatically), and will also not represent the actual header value of Content-Length that was sent to the server, since it is effectively ignored. This is one of many ways the platform tries to protect developers from doing something they shouldn't, like setting a value of 5 when you're only sending four bytes ('asdf'). This sort of bug would cause the system to hang until the maximum callout time (up to 120 seconds), which is obviously undesirable. The system automatically tries to fix up a request so it's HTTP/1.1 compliant, including adding a Host header (if you don't specify one), Content-Length for PATCH, PUT, and POST, and setting appropriate HTTP compression headers, if specified.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of explains why I can't override the the value. But question still remains, why can't I read the value.

Comment: @dzh I just tested this, and it seems that HttpRequest doesn't actually get modified upon sending the request; its values are exactly as they were before you sent the request. Ergo, if you set Content-Length to 5, you can read it back as 5, but that won't represent was actually sent to the server. In other words, it's more of a "dumb" object that just facilitates the request, and not a "smart" object that actually represents what's actually sent to the server.